4x4 Nonlinear Trigonometric System Solution
I am trying to solve the following 4x4 nonlinear system of equations, originating from the analysis of coupled transmission lines. It consists of two 2x2 matrix equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tan\varphi & -\cot\theta \\
-\cot\varphi & \tan\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tan(a\varphi) & -\cot(a\theta) \\
-\cot(a\varphi) & \tan(a\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The unknowns are $x$, $y$, $\varphi$ and $\theta$, while $a$ is a known constant. Assume that both trigonometric matrices are non-singular and notice that the two differ only by the multiplication by a nonzero $a$ in the trigonometric arguments. Also, the vector they multiply and the multiplication result are the same.
I would appreciate any ideas on how to approach this.
Thanks in advance

Maybe the way I expressed it was misleading. I meant assume (take as given, consider this specific case) that both trigonometric matrices are non-singular Also, as Dietrich pointed out, assume $a\neq0$.

I changed "consider" to "assume". You can rewrite this with $\tan(\phi)=r/s$, $\cot(\phi)=s/r$ and similarly for $\theta$ and the solve the linear equations, substituting  $r^2+s^2=1$ etc.

You are most likely looking at using numerical methods here. The system can be reduced to  system of two variables and two equations.

Isn't the first equation just a special case of the second with $a = 1$?

And, other that the fact that the coefficients have trig, this looks like a pretty standard system of equations.  What exactly makes it difficult for you to solve?
